# Difference between Hibernate session.getTransaction().begin() vs session.beginTransaction()

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I couldnt find much information on this topic. Can someone explain me whats the Difference between *Hibernate* `session.getTransaction().begin(`) vs `session.beginTransaction()` vs  `session.beginTransaction().begin()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Calling `session.getTransaction().begin()` doesn't make much sense as `session.getTransaction()` will retrieve the transaction already in progress because it assumes that a transaction is in progress. You are basically saying, begin this transaction that should already be in progress.

`session.beginTransaction()` will either begin a new Transaction if one isn't present, or it will use an existing transaction to begin the unit of work specified.

`session.beginTransaction().begin()` == `session.beginTransaction()`

For more information I suggest you have a look at the [Hibernate documentation](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/) for your version of Hibernate. You should only be dealing with the low levels of Hibernate like this if you are not using  a `TransactionManager` or you are using a `JDBCTemplate` so have a think because messing with transactions in this way gets messy fast.

Comment: Unfortunately, `session.getTransaction().begin()` is being used in [Transaction section of Hibernate User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#transactions).

Comment: "will retrieve the transaction already in progress" - but what if there isn't one in progress?