# Hibernate session.getTransaction().begin() vs session.beginTransaction()

Tags: java, hibernate, session, transactions

i was not able to get the difference b/w Hibernate session.getTransaction().begin() vs session.beginTransaction()..can anybody explain what is the difference b/w them and also when to use i.e., what should we  invoke in a single threaded and multi threaded env...

Comment: Hello @kotasrinu, this question already has been asked. Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196595/difference-between-hibernate-session-gettransaction-begin-vs-session-begintr

Comment: i was not able to completely understand about the session.getTransaction in the answer..so opened a new thread..:(