# database connection with hibernate doesn't update

Tags: java, hibernate, session, connection

Here is my database configuration to connect to db using hibernate:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
public static HibernateUtil mInstance = null;

public static HibernateUtil getInstance(DBMode dbMode) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new HibernateUtil(dbMode);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private HibernateUtil(DBMode dbMode) {
        buildSessionFactoryTest();
        }

private void buildSessionFactoryTest() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
            .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url",
                    "jdbc:mysql://ip:port/DB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&amp;characterSetResults=utf8&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "password")
            .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update").setProperty("c3p0.max_size", "20")
            .setProperty("c3p0.timeout", "1800").setProperty("3p0.min_size", "5")
            .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "0")
            .setProperty("connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider")
            .configure();
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
            .buildServiceRegistry();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
}

public Session getSession() {
    Session session;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
    if (session == null || sessionFactory.isClosed() || !session.isConnected() || !session.isOpen()) {
        sessionFactory.close();
            buildSessionFactoryTest();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
    return session;
}
```

}

and here is how I get session from HibernateUtil:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getInstance(dbMode).getSession();
```

My app works correctly most of the times, but sometimes when I add one object to database and execute a query, the new added object doesn't return. I guess the connection has been cached return old results. Do my configures have problem?

Comment: Some APIs like Session.get(Class, int) will always go to the database (instead of fetching cached data). I suggest that you read some Hibernate tutorial.

Comment: @dsp_user I guess going to database for new connection per request is expensive in time complexity, As my first connection to db after deployment runs always slow.

Comment: I'm not talking about creating a new db connection for every database operation. You should, of course, reuse your db connection. I'm just saying that some Hibernate APIs will always go the database and will thus fetch the most recent data/updates.

Comment: @dsp_user I expect all session would be update by default, Thanks for your comment. I read about them.

Comment: Show us the code that retrieves data from the DB that doesn't work and we may be able to provide more help.

Answer (score 0):

I could be that you are using transactions and are reusing them. If this is the case, you should start a new transaction for each thing you do.

for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24197494/3959856

You might also want to use

```
session.flush();
session.commit();
```

after adding and deleting.

Comment: I use transaction only when I update database, but for executing a 'select' query I don't start transactions.

Comment: Yes, I commit and flush the session after all changes